# how to show/hide component in react with mobX

Tags: reactjs, mobx

i have some trouble here, so i make simple contact list and i want the contact card in the right appears if i click the contact list in the left, maybe you could give me advice how to do that , so far i just looping each component and i plan to make onClick state to hidden or show the component but i think it's not good solution

gere's my code so far:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ContactTable from './ContactList'
import ContactCard from './ContactCard'
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react'
import DevTools from 'mobx-react-devtools'
import styles from './contact.css'

//import Component

@inject('store') @observer
export default class Contact extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    
    this.props.store.contact.loadParent()
    
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.store.contact.selected = !this.props.store.contact.selected
  }
  
  render() {
    var data = this.props.store.contact.fetchedData
    console.log(this.props.store.contact.selected)
    return (
      <div>
        <DevTools />>
        <ContactTable data={data} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
        {
          this.props.store.contact.selected ? <ContactCard person={data} /> : null
        }
      </div>
    )   
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is this code not giving you the effect you want? Isn't `ContactCard` displayed when you click `ContactTable`?

Comment: @Tholle it seems onClick function not working. when i clicked it, it didnt change {selected} state value to true / false in the store

Comment: I see. It seems to [**work for me**](http://jsbin.com/yaliguradi/edit?js,output). Is it any help?